# Opencart: MySQL query in the reports model is not retrieving data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm not sure if this is Opencart-related issue or just PHP/MySQL issue.

In `admin/model/report/test_module.php`, this is what I have:

```
class ModelReportTestModule extends Model {
  public function getData($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "test_module";

    if (!empty($data['filter_group'])) {
        $sql .= " WHERE url = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_group']) . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_start'])) {
        $sql .= " AND date >= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_start']) . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_end'])) {
        $sql .= " AND date <= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_end']) . "'";
    }


    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $result->rows;
  }
}
```

`$data`passed in the function above contains an array, something like this:

```
Array ( [filter_date_start] => 2013-07-10 [filter_date_end] => 2013-07-12 [filter_group] => http://localhost/oc-1.5.5.1/index.php?route=product/category&path=18 )
```

In the database, the values are stored in this format:

```
date(datetime): 2013-07-11 09:41:17
url(text): http://localhost/oc-1.5.5.1/index.php?route=product/category&path=18
```

If I run the query below directly in SQL console in phpMyAdmin, it works fine and gives me the correct rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_test_module` WHERE
`url` = 'http://localhost/oc-1.5.5.1/index.php?route=product/category&path=18' and
`date_time` >= '2013-07-10' and
`date_time` <= '2013-07-12';
```

However it fails to retrieve anything when I try it inside the report model, which is doing pretty much the same thing as the SQL query. I've spent hours but unable to figure out what I am missing. Maybe something trivial that I couldn't see.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is to do a `var_dump($sql);` on the line just before

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Then debug it in your PHPMyAdmin. It could be something trivial such as the `&` being `&amp;` in your query. Use a differencing tool between the working and non-working query if it's not immediately apparent what's causing the issue

Comment: Actually I had tried all that and copied that exact SQL query into PHPMyAdmin and it works there. But you are right about `&` and `&amp;`. `var_dump($sql);` displays the URL in this format - `http://localhost/oc-1.5.5.1/index.php?route=product/category&path=18` in the browser but using `preg_replace` to do something like this resolved the issue - `$this->db->escape(preg_replace('/&amp;/', '&', $data['filter_group']))`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, after I spent an hour I figure it out that I connect with different database. I mean my opencart connect to database 'DB1' but I run sql to database 'DB2' in phpmyadmin. Thats why I didn't got any result but didn't show any error.

Maybe you test it with different database so it showed different result.